# GSon Naming Policy Does Not Work With Java Map

Tags: java, hashmap, gson

I have created a java hash map and try to serialize it using gson. I used Naming policy for this serialization. Serialization was success but naming policy does not work for it.

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE_WITH_SPACES);
Gson gson = builder.create();

Map<String, String> resultData = new HashMap<>();
resultData.put("firstName","Kevin");
resultData.put("homeAddress","20/b,Colombo.");
resultData.put("passportNumber","1231239997M");

gson.toJson(resultData);
```

I want to get

```
{"First Name":"Kevin","Home Address":"20/b,Colombo.","Passport Number":"1231239997M",}
```

as the result.

but it always give

```
{"firstName":"Kevin","homeAddress":"20/b,Colombo.","passportNumber":"1231239997M"}
```

please let me know the way how can I to it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not possible using namingpolicy. You need dictionary to split words.

Comment: when i'm using  DTO(POJO) for do the same thing its work fine. I want to do it for HashMap.

Comment: Only thing I could do in this operation is inserting the keys into map. it update as we want.